Unable to convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy
I have y_hat variable of type list. I am unable to convert it to numpy array. It gives following error:
TypeError: can't convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first.

Also I cannot call .cpu() on it to move y_hat from CUDA to RAM.
Here is the screen grab of vscode debug console:

What I am missing here?

You fist need to offload tensor to cpu, then detach it from gradients and only then convert it to numpy:
y_hat.cpu().detach().numpy()

in your case most probably you have list of tensors inside y_hat. So you need to apply this procedure to each element of y_hat:
y_hat = [y.cpu().detach().numpy() for y in y_hat]


As you can see in the screenshot calling y_hat.cpu() gives AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'cpu'

yes, thus use list comprehension [y.cpu().detach().numpy() for y in y_hat]
